# Blocking apps for users in an office

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, system

I would like to block access to all apps except google chrome in my office, so that unnecessary time is not spent in the office premises. Is there any app or code by which this can be accomplished in Elementary OS?

Answer (score 1):

elementary OS ships with a feature called **Parental Control**. Naming aside, this should also work great in an office scenario.

1. Create a non-administrator user for the employee.
2. As the administrator user, open **System Settings** > **Parental Control** and set up the rules you'd like for the employee user.
3. *Optional.* Log into the employee account and ensure it's working as expected.